# Git-crypt workflow - deployment to multiple servers or circleci/travisci

Tags: security, deployment, continuous-deployment, gnupg, git-crypt

Trying to understanding the full workflow of a git-crypt based secret keeping solution.

The tool itself works pretty nicely when on a dev machine, even scaling to multiple developers seems to work fine.

However, it is not clear to me how will this work when deployed to a multiple servers on a cloud, some are created on-demand:

1. Challenge of unattended creation of GPG key on the new server (someone needs to create the passphrase, or is it in a source control, and than, what is all this even worth?)
2. Once a GPG is created, how is it being added to the ring?
3. Say we decide to skip #1 and just share a key across servers, how is the passphrase being supplied as part of the "git-crypt unlock" process?

I've really tried to search, and just couldn't find a good end-to-end workflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like many Linux tools, [`git-crypt`](https://github.com/AGWA/git-crypt) is an example of doing only one thing and doing it well. [This philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy#Origin) dictates that any one utility doesn't try to provide a whole suite of tools or an ecosystem, just one function that can be chained with others however you like. In this case `git-crypt` doesn't bill itself as a deployment tool or have any particular integrations into a workflow. Its job is just to allow the git repository to store sensitive data that can be used in some checkouts but not others. The use cases can vary, as will how you chain it with other tools.

Based on the wording of your question I would also clarify that `git-crypt` is not a "secret keeping solution". In fact it doesn't keep your secrets at all, it just allows you to shuffle around where you do keep them. In this case it enables you to keep secret data in a repository along side non-secret information, but it only does so at the expense of putting the secret keeping burden on another tool. It exchanges one secret for another: your project's version controlled secret component(s) for a GPG key. How you manage the secret is still up to you, but now the secret you need to handle is a GPG key.

*Holding* the secrets is still up to you. In the case of you and other developers that likely means having a GPG private key file kicking around in your home directory, hopefully protected by a passphrase that is entered into an agent before being dispensed to other programs like `git-crypt` that call for it.

In the case of being able to automatically deploy software to a server, something somewhere has to be trusted with real secrets. This is often the top-level tool like [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/products/engine) or [Puppet](https://puppet.com/products/puppet-pipelines), or perhaps a CI environment like [Gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com/features/), [Travis](https://travis-ci.org/), or [Circle](https://circleci.com/). Usually you wouldn't trust anything but your top level deployment tool with knowing when to inject secrets in an environment and when not to (or in the case of development / staging / production environments, *which* secrets to inject).

I am not familiar with Circle, but I know with Travis under your projects *Settings* tab there is an *Environment Variables* section that you can use to pass private information into the virtual machine. There is [some documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/best-practices-security/#Steps-Travis-CI-takes-to-secure-your-data) for how to use this. Gitlab's build in CI system has [something similar](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#protected-variables), and can pass different secrets to test vs. deploy environments, etc.

I would suggest the most likely use case for your work flow is to:

- Create a special secret variable for use on your production machines that has the passphrase for a GPG key used only for deployments. Whatever you use to create your machines should drop a copy of this key into the system and use this variable to unlock it and add it to an agent.
- The deploy script for your project would checkout your git project code, then check for a GPG agent. If an agent is loaded it can try to decrypted the the checkout.

In the case of a developer's personal machine this will find their key, in the case of the auto-created machines it will find the deploy key. Either way you can manage access to the secrets in the deployment environment like one more developer on the project.

Whatever tool you use to create the machines becomes responsible for holding and injecting the secrets, probably in the form of a private key file and a passphrase in an environment variable that is used to load the key file into an agent.